# Consulta SQL error al ejecutar

Tags: conversión-de-tipos, sql, sql-server-2012

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta en SQL Server en la cual hago:

```
Round(Convert(float,A)/(Convert(float,B),2)
```

y me devuelve este mensaje:

> The conversion of the nvarchar value '2968922618' overflowed an int column.

El valor del denominador es:

- b=4841517826

Si borro el número 6, el último dígito, funciona perfectamente. Pero si no, falla. ¿alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir la consulta completa? A simple vista parece que el problema es en la conversión de int a float (los valores pueden estar saliendo del rango permitido). Pero quizá con la consulta completa se pueda apreciar de otra manera.

Comment: El error parece querer decir que alguna columna de la tabla es más pequeña que el valor que intentas usar. Revisa el tamaño de las columnas que se ven afectadas por la operación que intentas hacer.

Comment: Ese es el problema que es un simple select:
when [Parametro]='B' and [b] is not null  AND [b]<>0 THEN Round(Convert(float,A)/(Convert(float,B),2)

esta es la línea completa,

Answer (score 3):

Es porque el valor máximo que puede recibir un campo `INT` es `2,147,483,647` y le estás intentando asignar `2,968,922,618`. Intenta hacer un `CAST` a `BIGINT`:

```
Cast(Round((Convert(float,A)/Convert(float,B)),2) as bigint)
```